# Proximity search for posts with multiple locations

Tags: php, html, mysql, wordpress, geolocation

I need help in modifying this WordPress function below to work for posts that have an array of latitude and longitude values stored as meta-data instead of posts with a single lat/long value.

The code below filters a bunch of posts for the ones that are located within a 1km radius or {whatever}km radius.

Each product has a meta-data ("meta_key ") which specifies a single location. These are "tl_geolocation_lat", "tl_geolocation_long", for example (tl_geolocation_lat => 42.32, tl_geolocation_lng => 72.32). The "$search_lat" & "$search_long" is the user's  current location and the "$search_radius" is the search radius. The post should be with 1km. If the posts has two lat/lng values that are within the search radius. The closest on should be picked.

I want to modify the dataset and SQL to look analyze multiple locations hence an array of lat and long, for example,  the meta_key dataset will now be (tl_geolocation_lat => [42.32, 64.98, 73.56, 78.90], tl_geolocation_lng => [42.32, 64.98, 73.56, 78.90]).

The end of the code just matches found products in the radius with a keyword/query the user types ("$query_args").

```
function tl_radius_filter_callback( $query_args, $search_lat, $search_long, $search_radius, $use_radius, $location ) {

global $wpdb;

if ( ! ( $use_radius && $search_lat && $search_long && $search_radius ) || ! $location ) {
    return $query_args;
}

$radius_unit = tl_option('radius_unit');
if( $radius_unit == 'km' ) {
    $earth_radius = 6371;
} elseif ( $radius_unit == 'mi' ) {
    $earth_radius = 3959;
} else {
    $earth_radius = 6371;
}

$sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT $wpdb->posts.ID,
        ( %s * acos(
            cos( radians(%s) ) *
            cos( radians( latitude.meta_value ) ) *
            cos( radians( longitude.meta_value ) - radians(%s) ) +
            sin( radians(%s) ) *
            sin( radians( latitude.meta_value ) )
        ) )
        AS distance, latitude.meta_value AS latitude, longitude.meta_value AS longitude
        FROM $wpdb->posts
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
            AS latitude
            ON $wpdb->posts.ID = latitude.post_id
        INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta
            AS longitude
            ON $wpdb->posts.ID = longitude.post_id
        WHERE 1=1
            AND ($wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' )
            AND latitude.meta_key='tl_geolocation_lat'
            AND longitude.meta_key='tl_geolocation_long'
        HAVING distance < %s
        ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.menu_order ASC, distance ASC",
    $earth_radius,
    $search_lat,
    $search_long,
    $search_lat,
    $search_radius
);
$post_ids = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, OBJECT_K );

if ( empty( $post_ids ) || ! $post_ids ) {
    $post_ids = array(0);
}

$query_args[ 'post__in' ] = array_keys( (array) $post_ids );
return $query_args;
}
```

Comment: This is an ill-advised strategy. Consider normalising your schema

Comment: Also, incorporating a bounding box will likely further improve performance